# Stack region determination for functions

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I have the image below and the `main` function calls `a = foo(12, 15, 18) ;`
In the image below, is the frame for `main` basically the whole of stack?
And the frame for `foo()` is where the EBP register of `main` is stored till it saves the registers?

Also, will a memory region be allocated for the variable `a`?

[image]

Comment: `is the frame for main basically the whole of stack?` - no, `main` is a function like any other except that it's the one called by the process start logic within the O/S. -- Whether the arguments passed to a function belong to the caller's stack frame of that of the callee is in the eye of the beholder. And whether a stack region will be allocated to `a` depends on what it's used for after the assignment (as well as compiler settings).

Comment: OK thank you, what if a is used for a multiplication with a constant?

Comment: It's going to depend on context. Try it yourself e.g. on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/).